# second step in creating google plus login button

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, google-plus

i'm having a page with google+ sign in button in this page www.mawk3y.net/glogin and here's the code
head code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();

function signinCallback(authResult) {
if (authResult['access_token']) {
  alert("done");
// Successfully authorized
// Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:
document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
} else if (authResult['error']) {
// There was an error.
// Possible error codes:
//   "access_denied" - User denied access to your app
//   "immediate_failed" - Could not automatically log in the user
// console.log('There was an error: ' + authResult['error']);
}
}

</script>
```

body code:

```
<span id="signinButton">
<span
class="g-signin"
data-callback="signinCallback"
data-clientid="451331211615.apps.googleusercontent.com"
data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
</span>
</span>
```

still the most important part which is how to retrieve the user information from google like name,email,gender,country any help please ?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have authenticated a user, and they have authorized you to get information about them, you can make calls to get that information using the plus.people.get method, or other related methods. See https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/ for the overview and links to more detailed information.

Specifically, you can see a code fragment at https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/#retrieve_profile_information that will retrieve all of a person's public data except for their email address. Typically, you would call this fragment as part of the loginFinishedCallback (shown further down on that page) once you have verified the authentication was good.

Comment: ok i'm using the code at the end of the page which fetches the email address so how can i get a list of elements like name , country ....... ?

Comment: i had changed https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.displayNam but i get invalid_scope message

Comment: The plus.login scope should be sufficient to get the additional profile info you need, but you need to do additional calls to get it. I have updated the answer to provide more info.

Comment: I've copied the code at the bottom of the page as i told you and the only thing i get is the email address and when trying to get any other information i get an error and working code as example so i can do it correctly ? thanks for your help

Comment: As I said, you need additional calls to get the information. There is a working code fragment in the middle of the page, in the section indicated, that you can use to get the remainder of the information.